# Date function VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to create a function to compare two dates in VBA (Date Required & Order Date),
if date required is earlier than order date then this should generate an error.

Comment: Try `datediff` :) If you have date variables then you can directly compare. How are the dates being passed to the function?

Comment: Can we safely assume you have tried nothing at all yourself?

Comment: Not entirely, i've done some stuff but in a long winded process of firstly making sure that the strings are being stored as dates using CDate. I then cant compare them with the criteria of if Date Required is earlier than Order Date then error message should appear.

Comment: So what problems are you facing with CDate?

Answer (score 3):

Further to my first comment, here are Four examples for date comparison

```
'~~> Direct Date Comparision
Sub Sample1()
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date

    dt1 = #12/12/2014#
    dt2 = #12/12/2013#

    Debug.Print IsGreater(dt1, dt2)
End Sub

'~~> Converting string to date and directly comparing
Sub Sample2()
    Dim dt1 As String, dt2 As String

    dt1 = "12/12/2014"
    dt2 = "12/12/2013"

    Debug.Print IsGreater(CDate(dt1), CDate(dt2))
End Sub

'~~> Using DateDiff with direct date comparision
Sub Sample3()
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date

    dt1 = #12/12/2014#
    dt2 = #12/12/2013#

    If DateDiff("d", dt2, dt1) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Greater"
    Else
        MsgBox "Smaller or Equal"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Using DateDiff with converting string to date and directly comparing
Sub Sample4()
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date

    dt1 = "12/12/2014"
    dt2 = "12/12/2013"

    If DateDiff("d", CDate(dt2), CDate(dt1)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Greater"
    Else
        MsgBox "Smaller or Equal"
    End If
End Sub

Function IsGreater(d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Boolean
    IsGreater = d1 > d2
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If dateRequired < orderDate Then
    Debug.Print "this should generate an error."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim orderdate As Date

Dim earlierdate As Date

orderdate = InputBox("Enter the orderdate")

earlierdate = "12 / 12 / 2011"

If orderdate > earlierdate Then

```
  MsgBox "Error"
```

End If